# Vuejs v-calendar

Tags: vue.js, vcalendar

[My Dispatch Calendar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Za3mw.jpg)

I am developing a scheduling calendar that displays each employee and the task assigned to them. I need help in changing the employee axis with the timeline. Similar to the following picture:
[Desired Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6t07I.png)

V-calendar code:

```html
<v-calendar    
      category-show-all
      ref="calendar"
      event-overlap-mode="stack"
      v-model="filter.date"
      type="category"
      :categories="category.list"
      :events="category.events"
      :event-color="getEventColor"
      :now="minimumDate"
      @change="getEvents"
      :row-height=60
      :interval-height="20"
      @click:event="showEvent">
</v-calendar>
```

I am not sure how to change the axis of v-calendar

Comment: there's nothing in [v-calendar documentation](https://vcalendar.io/) that suggests it's possible.  most likely need different library or make your own custom solution.  if you do find it possible with v-calendar, post your attempt and others can help you with specific issues if you encounter them.

Comment: Maybe look into Fullcalendar (https://fullcalendar.io/)